# Add some Operations to the back button of a NavigationViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to force the back button of my navigationViewController to call the dissmissmodalViewController to prevent the fact that the user tap the back button to fast and the app send a message to a deallocated instance... how can I solve?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question feels a bit odd because the back button typically does something like:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I'm not sure how that is impacting any modal view controllers.  If you really need to change its functionality, then you would basically hide the built in back button and replace it with your own custom one kind of like this: (put this in viewDidLoad)

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES]; //hide the built in button

//create your new button
UIBarButtonItem *b = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"new-back-button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(customBackButton:)];

//set the new button
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = b;
```

then setup your new method to handle the button push

```
- (IBAction)customBackButton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I call My View Controller with this methoed...
         OrientamentoViewController *viewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:item.URL];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
is it correct?

Comment: if your item.URL equal the string identifier code on the object in the storyboard, then it will work.  If your already in the storyboard wouldn't it be better to just use segue's?  Either way, you are using a push, so to remove it you use ...popViewController syntax from the answer.